# How to find popular and conventional electronic parts?

Tags: power-supply, rf, pcb-design

We have linear regulator: AMS1117 that I think it must be popular, since many company manufacturing this. Also some have changed it's name slightly to emphasis on their company like LM1117 and LT1117. I think a part has been populated, then many company has manufactured it to with that name and can be placed by previous one without any big stress. Is there some place that has been listed them? or this phenomena happening synonymous, only experience and encountering them in work will lead us to identify them?

Also is there any popular and standard RF component list (mixer, modulator, attenuator, lna ...)?

Comment: Look at the manufacturer’s catalogues.

Comment: I'm pretty sure LM1117 is the original and AMS1117 is the one where they modified the part number.

Comment: @SolarMike but I think catalog does not contain the parts history and it's impact on industry, isn't that?

Comment: LM is the old National Semiconductor, which was bought by TI -- but to complicate things, it was after National spun off Fairchild, which also sells "LM" parts.  LT is Linear Technology, which was bought by ADI (and Linear was founded by folks who left National over a disagreement about direction back in the 1970's or 1980's).

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd Because if I remember right, NatSemi originally developed the 1117. Also, why do you care about the part's history? Sure, that's an interesting topic, but it's not something you need to know to know what part to use.

Comment: @Hearth, How you are sure since LM is TI and LT is from ADI, both are well known manufacturer! Why they've modified it?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd Don't ask me. Ask LT/AD.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are concerned about availability in case you want to mass replicate your project. Availability is strongly dependent on geographic location. A component may be easy to obtain at a downtown store, but not in "rural" areas, and so you would have to make mail orders, right?. A hint would be visiting the online parts catalog of a couple local stores (and make sure they are listed because they are in normal stock, not because they COULD be ordered).
I once wanted to build a PLL synthesizer. 1st thing I did before drafting the design was asking my local store what models they were already bringing because some manufacturer was already purchasing them.

Comment: You exactly explained my demand! But really AMS1117 is not a widely used component, and the component popularity is strictly local?

Comment: You may already know the AMS1117 is a 1A low-dropout linear regulator. It is used e.g. in my Arduino. There are versions depending on the suffix: fixed voltage (e.g. 3.3 and 5V) or adjustable. It is called low-dropout because it needs the input to be just 1.3V higher than the desired output.
If you don't need this feature, you may use a standard 1A regulator such as the fixed 78xx, or the adjustable LM317, they need at least 2V Vin-Vout but are more popular. 
If feed from a rectifier plus capacitor, take into acount the ripple valley voltage when calculating the needed Vin.

Comment: AMS1117 does not pertain to specific company, this can be manufactured by anyone? this is not standard this is just popularity of LM1117, isn't that?

Comment: Yes, I see they are similar. There are some differences: max input is 20V for the LM, 15V for the AMS. 1A for LM, 0.8A for AMS. 
BTW, the NCP1117 is similar too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, still there is part of my question that has no answer: Is there list of popular part like LM1117, to ensure that not only this part is abundant but also there is vast equivalent part?

Comment: I'm sorry, it would be good for such a list to exist, both for experimenters and small enterpreneurs! But I don't know of that.